# Codeigniter: You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload an image using codeigniter and no matter what
I keep getting "You did not select a file to upload" error.

Here's my Controller:

```
<?php
    class Post extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index(){
            $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ''));
        }

        function upload(){          
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '1024';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                echo json_encode($error);
            }
            else
            {
                $file_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $data['img'] = base_url().'/images/'.$file_data['file_name'];
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
    }
    }
?>
```

Here is my View:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-9"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Select File To Upload:<br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile"  />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A SOLUTION

I fixed it by following this tutorial.

http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/

Thanks to everyone who answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

on which function you are submitting form,as per code index function loading form and you are submitting on same page in stead of upload function